# Spliting integers from string in python

Tags: python

Suppose I have a numpy array like -

```
A = ['83.56%' '2.74%' '2.74%' '4.11%' '4.11%' '19.18%' '76.71%' '20.55%'
 '34.25%' '54.79%']
```

and I want to split this array as integers array only like -

```
B = ['83.56' '2.74' '2.74' '4.11' '4.11' '19.18' '76.71' '20.55'
 '34.25' '54.79']
```

How should I do it using Python codes ?

Comment: Those are not integers, those are floats.

Answer (score 0):

Use-case for `str.rstrip`:

```py
B = [item.rstrip('%') for item in A]
```

Comment: I used this script but the output came like - ['83.56%2.74%2.74%4.11%4.11%19.18%76.71%20.55%34.25%54.79'] ........



I want the output as ['83.56' '2.74' '2.74' '4.11' '4.11' '19.18' '76.71' '20.55' '34.25' '54.79']

Comment: You are missing the item separators (',') in your list A. This is also why your snippet does not do what you think it does and why it has been downvoted.

Comment: That, and it's not a NumPy array...

Comment: When I am using for one element only, it works fine; but not for the whole numpy array.

Comment: @SoumavNath You only have one element (because of the lack of commas), and it's not a NumPy array, it's a list.

Comment: Okay, then how should I modify the code for the list. I am just a beginner in python; kindly help me out.

Comment: @SoumavNath as we mentioned, you need commas between the values. But honestly, if you're just starting out, you should be reading tutorials and documentation until you understand the basics. Then you'll have the vocabulary to [search for answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) to your questions; and if you can't find them, *then* is the time to ask on here.